# What does above exception points to in exception info thrown?

Tags: python, exception, try-except

The simplest built-in exception as below:

```
>>> 1/0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Throw exception info ,then whole press is done.

Define function `f1` and not to define `myException`:

```
def f1():
    try:
        print(1/0)
    except:
        raise myException('my exception')
```

Call `f1()`:

```
>>> f1()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in f1
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in f1
NameError: name 'myException' is not defined
```

When the info

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in f1
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

thrown out,exception of `print(1/0)` is handled as we have seen that in the beginning.
Why the statement in the middle line is `During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:` ,instead of `After handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:`?
What is `above exception` in the statement `During handling of the above exception`?It points to `try ... except` structure in `f1` ,instead of exception resulted by `1/0`?
If `above exception` points to exception resulted by `1/0`,then `After handling of the above exception, another exception occurred` is better to describe all the exceptions here!

Comment: Because _within the `except` block_, where you are supposedly handling a caught exception, you were producing another exception. Indicating that your exception handler is faulty.

Comment: What is `above exception` in the statement `During handling of the above exception`?It points to `try ... except` structure in `f1` ,instead of exception resulted by `1/0`?

Comment: What makes you say that? Line 3 is the one with the `1/0` on it.

Comment: Its normal to catch and convert exceptions like this. It doesn't mean your exception handler is faulty. It just means that your module want's to raise its own custom exceptions according to its own rules.

Comment: @tdelaney That would be fine if you did `raise MyException from e`. Without the explicit `from e`, Python assumes the newly raised exception was a new error. As it indeed was in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exception chaining as described in [The `raise` Statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement). You catch the `ZeroDivisionError`. When you raise `MyException`, python will automatically add the current exception to its `__cause__` attribute.

That's why you see both exceptions listed. The one you raised, and the one put in the `__cause__` attribute. Python lets you customize the exception in several ways, particularly with a "from" exception. Generically, that's

```
raise myException from OtherException
```

More specifically, to fully suppress the original exception and keep it out of the `__cause__` attribute, raise from `None`:

```
raise myException from None
```

Comment: The key question --What does `above exception` points to in the statement `During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:`?

Comment: What isn't clear? Your code excepted on `1/0`. While handling that exception, it raised `myException`. "During the handling of the above exception" ... that is your generic `except:` handler, "another exception occurred"  .... that is your `raise myException`.

Comment: Then it is better to say  `After handling of the 1/0, another exception occurred`?More concret.

Comment: @showkey "After" would be appropriate if the `except` block completed without error. But it didn't. Within the `except` block is "while handling". The "handling" hasn't completed yet. Yes, the `except` statement has caught the exception, so it _has been caught_. But it hasn't been "handled" yet, i.e. you didn't complete your "plan B in case of an error" yet.

Comment: As @deceze says, you raised myException in your exception handler. So its "While handling" not "After handling". In your case, since you are purposely raising the exception, its that final thing you intend to do. But suppose you had a more complex handler and it raised an exception you didn't expect - maybe a bug in your code. "While handling" would make a lot of sense there.

Comment: @tdelaney Do note that in OP’s example it *is* an unexpected NameError while trying to raise a custom exception!

Comment: @deceze - I meant that in the sense that if it was a multiline exception suite with an error in the middle, it would be more obvious why its "while" and not "after". In OP's case, its on the last line where control was intended to be passed back to the caller, error or not, giving maybe some small support to "after".